# Make categories from string in XML data

Tags: ios, swift, xml

I looked everywhere but I don't see anything specific to the thing I am trying to achieve, especially with iOS/swift. I would like to make age categories from the XML parser request I am calling in my app.

The age information will have to be called from the  tag in the xml data:

```
<item>
<description>ANTHONY JOHNSON, Age: 17 From: PEORIA, IL</description></item>
```

I already have a call to get the description tag in full:

```
func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, 
 namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) { 

 if elementName == "description" {
        self.person.desc = self.foundCharacters; }

     if elementName == "item" {
tempData.desc = self.person.desc; }
```

Item class:

```
 class Item { 
  var desc = "";
}
```

I just need to make categories from the age value only. I plan on using them with an enum:

```
enum ageCategories: String {

    case ageUnder10 = "Age 10 and under"
    case age10Plus = "Age 10-15"
    case age15Plus = "Age 15+"
}
```

My questions are:

- Do I make a call in the XML parser to get the ages? How would I organize the call to get the ages part of the description string only and put them in categories?

OR

- Is there an easier way to call just the ages from the string I have already called in the XML parser and then make categories with that? i.e: replacingOccurrences(range searchRange:"Age")

Comment: Since your actual question is more about how to extract the age from a string, you should refocus your question on just that part. The fact that the string came from XML parsing is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks. I was just trying to decide if I needed to add another function to the parser to get the age string or use another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question boils down to finding an age in the description string. The following shows one solution using `Scanner`. This code assumes that the age will be a number after the text "Age:".

```
let desc = "ANTHONY JOHNSON, Age: 17 From: PEORIA, IL"
var ageRange: ageCategories? = nil

let scanner = Scanner(string: desc)
if scanner.scanUpTo("Age:", into: nil) && scanner.scanString("Age:", into: nil) {
    var age = 0
    if scanner.scanInt(&age) {
        switch age {
        case 0..<10:
            ageRange = .AgeUnder10
        case 10..<15:
            ageRange = .Age10Plus
        case 15...:
            ageRange = .Age15Plus
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

if let ageRange = ageRange {
    print("Found age range of \(ageRange)")
} else {
    print("No valid age found")
}
```

Adjust the ranges in the `case` statements to match your actual needs. The strings you are assigning to your enum values are ambiguous. Is 10 supposed to be `.AgeUnder10` or `.Age10Plus`?

FYI - enum values should start with lowercase letters and the enum name should start with uppercase. So your enum should be:

```
enum AgeCategories: String {
    case ageUnder10 = "Age under 10"
    case age10Plus = "Age 10-14"
    case age15Plus = "Age 15+"
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Age 10 will be included with 10 and under.

Comment: how would I organize these scanner values and put them into an array of data categorized by age? I want to show the data by child age

Comment: @itsmcgh That's a whole new question.

Comment: I've banged my head against the wall long enough: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49054453/passing-xml-array-data-to-collectionview-via-tableview